# htaccess pagination modrewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Looking for some help with some pagination and  mod-rewrite
okay so i've got a url that looks like this

`www.website.com/page.php?phone=111-393-4949`

and I'm rewriting it to look like this...

`www.website.com/701-625-5444.php`

with this

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+) page.php?number=$1-$2-$3 [L,QSA]
```

I'm having some issues with adding my pagination to the mod rewrite now.
I am really not too sure on what all I need to do here but this is what I've come up with

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/([^/]*) page.php?number=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

which should output..

`www.website.com/494-949-9494/1.php`

what is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `()` pair is a capture group. Since you already have three `()` groups for the phone number, the `([^/]*)` you added will be captured in `$4`.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ page.php?number=$1-$2-$3&page=$4 [L,QSA]
```

If the pagination is optional, add an optional non-capturing group `(?:)?` around the final segment:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)(?:/([^/]*))?$ page.php?number=$1-$2-$3&page=$4 [L,QSA]
```

I will note that your `RewriteRule` does not forcefully include the `.php` as in your example `www.website.com/701-625-5444.php`.  That would look like

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.php$ page.php?number=$1-$2-$3 [L,QSA]
# Or...
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)(?:/([^/]*))?\.php$ page.php?number=$1-$2-$3&page=$4 [L,QSA]
```